# How to add custom exclude parameter via zap API

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm looking for a way how to add custom ignore parameter via api. I.E. api equivalent of this UI screen

[image: Zap UI - adding exclude parameter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid thats not supported by the API at the moment :(

Could you raise an enhancement request for that? 
https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new
I'm happy to do that for you, but if you do it then you'll get notified when we start working on it etc.

Thanks, Simon